# How to highlight the edited file using git in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Eclipse will highlight the files that I have made changes in git repository, but looks like intellij don't highlight that. Is there any preference that I can configure ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` -> `Version Control` then edit your project for setting git root. After that IDEA will show all changes in your files.